# new Date fail parsing for "31" but not "32"

Tags: javascript, date

I'm playing with Date to try to get a full year from 2 digits year and I noticed some inconsistency:

```
$ new Date("12")
Sat Dec 01 2001 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)
$ new Date("13")
Invalid Date
$ new Date("31")
Invalid Date
$ new Date("32")
Thu Jan 01 2032 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)
$ new Date("99")
Fri Jan 01 1999 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)
$ new Date("999")
Tue Jan 01  999 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)
```

Any reasonable explanation for this nonsense.

Browser is Chrome on OSX

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-value

Comment: Since all of those are out-of-spec, Chrome is allowed to fall back on its own heuristics. This is a great example of why it's best to avoid relying on unspecified behavior.

Comment: What is expected result for `new Date("13")`, and `new Date("31")`?

Comment: I would expect 01 Jan 2013 and 01 Jan 2031, to me `new Date("99")` is most accurate

Comment: Why do you expect that result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since all of those are out-of-spec, Chrome is allowed to fall back on its own heuristics. This is a great example of why it's best to avoid relying on unspecified behavior.

`new Date(string)` parses the string just like `Date.parse(string)` does. Here's what [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date.parse) says:

> The function first attempts to parse the format of the String according to the rules (including extended years) called out in Date Time String Format ([20.3.1.16](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date-time-string-format)). If the String does not conform to that format the function may fall back to any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats.

So, again, we're out of spec if we feed it `"32"` or similar.

**So what is Chrome doing? Or more accurately, what is V8 doing?** For that, we have to [hit the source](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/140ec9d7cc3bf5098ed26e1e14ed7cca85ba4fe7/src/dateparser-inl.h), in which I found this handy comment:

> An unsigned number followed by ':' is a time value [snip]...
>   **Any other number is a date component and is added to DayComposer.**

E.g., it's going to take `"12"` and `"31"` and such and try to figure out what part of a date they are, if possible. When doing so, it appears to try to match to months if values are < 13, give up on 13-31 (e.g., possibly day values), and above that go for years.

So clearly from your examples:

> ```
> $ new Date("12")
> Sat Dec 01 2001 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)
> ```

It decided the 12 was a month and defaulted the year to 2001.

> ```
> $ new Date("13")
> Invalid Date
> $ new Date("31")
> Invalid Date
> ```

In that range where it can't figure out what it is.

> ```
> $ new Date("32")
> Thu Jan 01 2032 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)
> ```

We're past the point it could be a day, so it's going for years in the current century now.

> ```
> $ new Date("99")
> Fri Jan 01 1999 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)
> ```

Years in the last century; fairly common in two-digit year handling to have a range that defaults to 1900s and the remainder defaulting to 2000s.

> ```
> $ new Date("999")
> Tue Jan 01  999 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)
> ```

Three digits, has to be a year, no need to infer century.

The moral of the story: Stick to specified input formats, or parse the date yourself. :-)

Comment: really nice answer. Go and have my upvote. I deleted mine because obviously was incorrect

Answer (score 1):

From Doc [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

> parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse, they are equivalent) is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies. Support for RFC 2822 format strings is by convention only. Support for ISO 8601 formats differs in that date-only strings (e.g. "1970-01-01") are treated as UTC, not local.
>
> **The string should be in a format recognized by the [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) method**

If UTC is expected then it should be written

```
new Date(Date.UTC(31)) //    Invalid Date
new Date(Date.UTC(32)) //    Invalid Date
new Date(Date.UTC(12)) //    Invalid Date
new Date(Date.UTC(13)) //    Invalid Date
new Date(Date.UTC("31")) //Invalid Date
new Date(Date.UTC("32"))  //Invalid Date
```

Comment: Riyaj - The spec requires at least two arguments to [`Date.UTC`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date.utc): *"When the UTC function is called with fewer than two arguments, the behaviour is implementation-dependent."*

Comment: @RobG: See above, `Date.UTC` is undefined and implementation-dependent for a single argument. FWIW, for me, new Date(Date.UTC(31)) produces an invalid date on Chrome (56.0.2924.87) and Firefox (51.0.1) (Linux).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder—wow, I missed that, :-( Anyhow, the OP isn't using *Date.UTC* so I guess this answer is kind of irrelevant.